# Visual stuidio publish query

Tags: visual-studio

Q1. How can I (if I can) publish a website project with source code? Whenever I publish my website, it converts .cs files to DLLs in bin folder. But I want it to pe published with cs files and all refered external DLLs

Q2. When I publish a web application project, it gives publish/package settings options which is not available for website projects. This setting tab does give options to copy with source code but it creates many other unwanted files like config.debug, config.release etc. How can I make it publish application with files already in the project and nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Copy site" instead of "Publish site" (right click on the web project or click "Web site" menu).